# Using SelectMany to get collection of entities with parents throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, ef-core-3.0

I have a DB Model which has a Parent Property of it's own type like this:

```
public class MainModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Entity Entity { get; set; };
}

public class Entity 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Entity Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to get a collection of all Entities related to an instance of MainModel.
So far I have tried to use SelectMany, creating a new Array of Entity containing the Entity itself and its parent. But this throws an InvalidOperationException

```
modelInstances.SelectMany(m => new []{ m.Entity, m.Entity.Parent });
```

Exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
Processing of the LINQ expression 'm => new Entity[]
{
    m.Entity,
    m.Entity.Parent,
    m.Entity.Parent.Parent 
}' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. 
This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in  EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
```

I'm somewhat confused since in the EFCore [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#selectmany) it says that SelectMany **is** supported by LINQ-to-SQL

Does somebody know what I might be missing here? 
Or another way of getting a list of the entity with it's parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that it can't translate the creation of an array to SQL.
I would try to load the data you want in a form that is supported by Entity Framework.

I would select the data, get it from the DB and then transform the result the way you want. Something like:

```
var listOfEntitiesAndParents = modelInstances.Select(m => new { m.Entity, m.Entity.Parent }).ToList();

var flatList = listOfEntitiesAndParents.SelectMany(e=>new [] {e.Entity, e.Parent}).ToList();
```

OR
    var flatList = listOfEntitiesAndParents.Select(e=>e.Entity).Union(listOfEntitiesAndParents.Select(e=>e.Parent)).ToList();

Hope this helps